# Change ng-include template rendered inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got an ng-repeat where each of the instances contains an `ng-include`. Like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-actions" ng-include="actionsTemplate"></div>
</li>
```

I would now like to be able to set and remove the `actionsTemplate` source with the click of a button in the same scope, like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-actions" ng-include="actionsTemplate"></div>
    <button ng-click="toggleActionsTemplate()">Toggle Actions</button>
</li>
```

So clicking the button would trigger a function `toggleActionsTemplate()` to set the `actionsTemplate` source to `foo`, or if it's already set to `foo`, set it to `null` to remove the template.

I've tried doing this but can't figure out how get a controller function to target the template inside the same `ng-repeat` instance the function is being called from.

Is this possible, and more importantly, is this a good way of going about achieving this behaviour?

Comment: On which scope `actionsTemplate` is located?

Comment: The source variable `actionsTemplate` is specified in my controller (i.e. `items.js`) on $scope. The actual `foo` template itself is contained in the markup, also within the controller (i.e. in `items.html`). Hope this answers your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4p56QeuqpMAH1yc0tbfy?p=preview

- You need to initialize a different `actionsTemplate` variable for each child scope inside `ngRepeat`.
- You can use `ngInit` to initialize a scope variable.

#### An example:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="action = actionsTemplate">
    <div class="item-actions" ng-include="action"></div>
    <button ng-click="action = toggleAction(action)">Toggle Actions</button>
</li>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.toggleAction= function(action){
  return action === 'foo' ? null : 'foo';
}
```